# Mandar informacion de un formulario a otro formulario

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de mandar la información con inputs hidden de un resultado que obtengo de mi consulta hacia otro formulario, si me aparece la información pero al dar en el boton enviar en el segundo formulario no aparece la información de los input, dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar, este es el código del formulario donde quiero que se vea la info:

```
<td><label for="">NOMBRE COMPLETO:</label></td>
            <td><input class="estilo" type="text" value="<?php echo $txtnombre; ?>" name="txtnombre" id="txtnombre" placeholder=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="">ID USUARIO:</label></td>
            <td><input class="estilo" type="text" value="<?php echo $txtusuario; ?>" name="txtusuario" id="txtusuario" placeholder=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

y aqui esta el codigo de los input ocultos que deberian mandar la info al otro formulario:

```
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php   echo $ver[1] ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php   echo $ver[2] ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php   echo $ver[4] ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php   echo $ver[5] ?></td>
                <td>

                <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="txtnombre" value="<?php   echo $ver[1] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="txtusuario" value="<?php   echo $ver[2] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="txtdepto" value="<?php   echo $ver[4] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="txtuser" value="<?php   echo $ver[5] ?>">

                <input type="button" value="seleccionar" name="accion">

                </form>
```

Comment: El formulario esta funcionando correctamente. En donde asignas el valor a `$txtnombre`? probaste imprimir por consola `$ver` para asegurarte que contiene los datos?

Comment: si asi es y si trae los datos

Comment: @Xavi a esta pregunta le falta información importante para entender el problema: ¿qué es `$ver`? ¿dónde y cómo asignas el valor de `$txtusuario` y `$txtnombre`? ¿Están esos dos snippets en la misma página? ¿cómo se relacionan? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar una nueva medalla.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas modificar tu etiqueta  
de:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

a:

```
<form action="Formulario2.php" method="POST">
```

la propiedad **`action`**, te dice donde se va a enviar la información del formulario.